# how to check function value?

Tags: javascript

consider this code

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkform(form); someotherfunction();"
```

where checkform returns either true or false, the function being used in a form.

how can i check if the `checkform()` value is false then cancel the input so it dosen't call `someotherfunction()` and if its true vice versa.

i have tried

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="return checkform(form); someotherfunction();"
```

which dosen't call `someotherfunction()` at all because it's returning no matter the value, how can i check if `checkform()` is true so it can then call `someotherfunction()`?

i don't want to check the value of `checkform()` inside `someothefunction()`, is it possible to check in the `<input` line?

Answer (score 1):

`if`:

```
onclick="if(checkform(form)){someotherfunction();}"
```

Comment: You could also do `onclick="checkform(form) && someotherfunction();"`

Comment: You and your fancy short-circuiting... /rabble

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
<script>
var formExist = true;

function someotherfunction(){
   if(formExist){
        // do your stuff...
   }
}
</script>

<body>
...

<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="formExist = checkform(form); someotherfunction();" />

...
</body>
```

if this will not work perfect than use same mechanism but call someotherfunction () in checkform(),
definetely work....